# While Loops: simple division program outputting zero, don't understand why

Tags: c++, loops

DIRECTIONS:Write a while loop that prints userNum divided by 2 (integer division) until reaching 1. Follow each number by a space. Example output for userNum = 40: 
20 10 5 2 1

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int userNum;

   cin >> userNum;

   while (userNum >= 1) {
      userNum = userNum / 2;
      cout << userNum << " ";
   }

   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT: (userNum = 40; 20 10 5 2 1 0)

Comment: What happens when userNum equals 1?

Comment: 1/2 is 0. Everything seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```
userNum = userNum / 2;
cout << userNum << " ";
```

When `userNum = 1` (The final iteration of the loop) - 1/2 = 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an integer division .
Hence 1/2 = 0.5 after truncation it will be 0

By reading your question , it seems like you don't want the division of 1/2 to be done.

If so, check the condition in your while Loop 
Make it  userNum > 1 instead of userNum >= 1